# Customize the layout of the page (non-publishing)

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer

In SharePoint 2013, how do I customize the layout of the web zones for a non-publishing site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

option 1:

1. download sharepoint designer
2. open site > select page.aspx > edit the page any way you like
3. save it

option 2:

1. open the your site in webdav (net use x: \mysite)
2. go to x:\ choose correct folder of library e.g. "SitePages"
3. open page.aspx with notepad and customize the layout, save it

option 3:

etc...